# How does Flyby Attack work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The explanation of [Flyby Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/flyby-attack) is a little unclear to me, just want to clarify a few things.

Is it saying that you can move your total fly speed and attack during the move?

So, for example, if your fly speed is 40 ft, can you move 20 ft, into range of a creature, attack it, and move the other 20 ft away?

I assume this provokes an AoO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A creature with the [Flyby Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/flyby-attack) feat can, on its turn, spend both a move action and standard action to...

- take a move action and travel X ft., where X is up to its speed *then*...
- take a standard action (doing whatever it wants with the standard action; e.g. make a standard attack, cast a spell with a casting time of 1 standard action) *then*...
- travel up to Y ft., where Y is the creature's Speed - X.

Attacks of opportunity are unaffected by the feat--therefore the creature's movement, standard action, or both provoke (or don't provoke) attacks of opportunity as usual.